# Default page links not working in IE 10 on one server but working fine on other with same configuration

Tags: asp.net, iis-7.5, internet-explorer-10, windows-server-2008-r2, dopostback

i have deployed my application from IIS 6.0 to IIS 7.5. the website links does not work in IE 10 from Prod but from uat the website is accessible. both the server are same. 
Does anyone know why this is happening in only one server and not the other. Do i need to change some setting in IIS or config file. I am getting the error of

SCRIPT5007: The value of the property '__doPostBack' is null or undefined, not a Function object

Can anyone please help i am facing this issue on production.

Comment: I have that same problem - did you find an answer?

Answer (score 0):

"There is a bug in the browser definition files that shipped with .NET 2.0 and .NET 4, namely that they contain definitions for a certain range of browser versions. But the versions for some browsers (like IE 10) aren't within those ranges any more. Therefore, ASP.NET sees them as unknown browsers and defaults to a down-level definition, which has certain inconveniences, like that it does not support features like JavaScript."

http://www.hanselman.com/blog/BugAndFixASPNETFailsToDetectIE10CausingDoPostBackIsUndefinedJavaScriptErrorOrMaintainFF5ScrollbarPosition.aspx

Maybe that could be it?

Answer (score 0):

Thought I'd share for posterity since every page on the internet links to the browser files issue.

This can also be caused in some cases by a change in the .Net Framework 4+ where encoding the __doPostBack encodes a single quote (it did not do this in 3.5).

I was able to fix a LinkButton with that error by manually putting the __doPostBack into the OnClientClick, overriding the href and not encoding a single quote.  Granted, maybe not clean, but it worked for me.

http://www.blakepell.com/asp-net-4-5-1-linkbutton-the-value-of-the-property-__dopostback-is-null-or-undefined-not-a-function-object